# How to tag a comment with the blog post in django?

Tags: python, django

i am new to django and am currently working on developing a blog.

I am trying to insert a comment form for my viewers using the CreateView template. Viewers will need to log in to type their comment. Their username will be tagged to the comment for the respective blog without them needing to indicate anything. There are no errors but data is not stored as expected. Comment is accepted but does not appear on the blog. Went to check on django administration where apparently only the author is stored but not the blog post that comment is on. Below is my code that is stored in the (views.py).

```
class CommentCreate(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['comment','blog']
    template_name = 'catalog/blog_comment.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CommentCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['blog'] = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk = self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super(CommentCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self): 
        return reverse('blog-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk'],})
```

The models Blog and Comment is defined as below in a separate file (models.py)

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)    
    blogger = models.ForeignKey('Blogger', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
null=True)  
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text='Write some stuffs 
for your blog')
    post_date = models.DateField(default=date.today)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['post_date',"title","blogger"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog-detail', args=[str(self.id)])


class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text='Comment on the 
 blog')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    blog = models.ForeignKey("Blog", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-post_date']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment
```

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What DIY blog project are you refering to? And what is the problem exactly, do you get an error? Or is data just not stored as expected? What is the model definition of `Comment`?

Comment: Hi. I have appended the question with more information and tried to phrase the problem to make it clearer. I don't have any errors but the data is not stored as expected. You are able to post a comment but comment is not registered where "Comment" is not tagged to the blog post.

Comment: You need to show your blog_comment template as well. How are you sending the data? Are you sure it is valid? I'm surprised for example that you have `blog` as a form field, I would expect you to set that in form_valid like you do with author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. Turns out i forgot to save the data in the form_valid.
Appended code is listed as below.

```
class CommentCreate(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['comment','blog']
    template_name = 'catalog/blog_comment.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CommentCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['blog'] = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk = self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk = self.kwargs['pk'])
        return super(CommentCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```